# File Size Goes to Zero when Returning FileStreamResult from MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-blob-storage

I am attempting to download a file from Azure Storage in the form of an CloudBlockBlob. I want to allow the user to select where to put the downloaded file, so I have written the following code to do this

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> DownloadFile(string displayName)
{
    ApplicationUser user = null;
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        // Retrieve storage account and blob client.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"]);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(
            VisasysNET.Utilities.Constants.ContainerName);

        // If the container does not exist, return error.
        if (container.Exists())
        {
            foreach (IListBlobItem item in container.ListBlobs(null, false))
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
                    if (blob.Name.CompareNoCase(displayName))
                    {
                        string contentType = String.Format(
                            "application/{0}", 
                            Path.GetExtension(displayName).TrimStart('.'));

                        // No need to dispose, FileStreamResult will do this for us.
                        Stream stream = new MemoryStream();
                        await blob.DownloadRangeToStreamAsync(stream, null, null);
                        return File(stream, contentType, displayName);
                    }
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Tools");
        }
    }
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);
}
```

This downloads the file from the blob storage fine, but when the controller returns to the view using `FileStreamResult`, the browser is launching the save file dialog as expected but the file size is 0 bytes. The `Stream` shows that the correct file size, but when I do

```
 return File(stream, contentType, displayName);
```

the data does not seem to be passed to the save dialog.

**How can I get the file to save properly?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried resetting the stream index back to zero just before returning the File result?

Comment: No I haven't. I wasn't aware that this could make a difference. Why would this help? I will try it now regardless. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This helps because reading or writing a stream moves its position.  i.e. Write file to stream sets position at the end of written data ready for more writing.  Then your File() tries to Read, it starts at the current position, reads nothing (we're at the end already).  If you set to zero, that read starts at zero and reads all the stuff you wrote.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your memorystream position after `DownloadRangeToStreamAsync` will be on the last byte. Set it back to the begining before you return it.

```
stream.Seek(0,0)
```

Comment: an hour of debuging and searching and you just hiding write here
thank you
fixed my issue with asp core FileStreamResult Content-Length: 0